# How do I prevent a script from changing the window.location or doing a reload on the current page?

Tags: javascript

I would like to prevent a third party script from changing the window.location and or reloading the current page with Javascript. Is there a way to monitor the location changes or window reload events and cancel them. I don't have control over the JavaScript library that does this and I need to temporary prevent page reloads during critical operations. I'm not trying to stop the user from reloading the page, just other scripts. jQuery solutions are welcome.

Thanks!

**EDIT**: the solution only needs to work in Firefox.

Comment: If you don't trust the script you probably shouldn't include it. Otherwise, it can spy on the user, `alert` messages, load other, forth-party scripts, and more.

Comment: @Kobi - I do trust the script it just likes to refresh the page at inopportune times like during ajax calls or ajaxed file uploads that my script does.

Comment: In that case, the best solution here is probably an angry email `:)`.

Comment: I agree, chances are it's reloading the page for a reason. I'd take the script out or have a new one made if possible. *Dirty eww gesture*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For preventing `reload()` you can do something like this:

```
var canReload = true;
var realReload = window.reload;
window.reload = function() {
  if (canReload) { 
    realReload();
  }
}
```

Basically override the `reload` function with your own. I'm not sure the same can be done  with a property assignment (where `window.location` is set). You could look into custom getter/setter (`__defineSetter__`) functions for Firefox, and create a setter for the `location` property of `window`.